# Is there a macro within VBA for Word that automatically changes a text at different locations?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently busy with automating some word files for my company. At this point I'm having some trouble with automating a certain part of the document. Up until now I have used this code to automatically fill in a certain area marked with a specific text field (in this case; initialen_achternaam):

```
Sub Document_Open()
ActiveDocument.FormFields("initialen_achternaam").Result = InputBox("Wat zijn de initialen en achternaam van de nieuwe medewerker?", "", "A. de Vries")
End Sub
```

This code, after answering the input box, automatically displays the answer at the specified area. However, certain answers to these input boxes need to be shown in multiple areas. Does anyone know how to enable this?

Also, I want a certain paragraph to be dependent on the answer to an inputbox. So, let's say if the answer to the above-mentioned inputbox is yes, then it shows paragraph A, else it shows paragraph B. I don't know how to write this code nor how to mark it in the word document to settle position of the paragraph.

Comment: You need to create an intermediate variable to store the `InputBox` result, then use that variable to copy the value to the `FormFields` and other areas.

Answer (score 0):

An illustration of PeterT's suggestion:

```
Sub Document_Open()
    Dim InputText As String
    InputText = InputBox("Wat zijn de initialen en achternaam van de nieuwe medewerker?", "", "A. de Vries")
    With ActiveDocument
        .FormFields("initialen_achternaam").result = InputText
        .FormFields("formfield2").result = InputText
        .FormFields("formfield3").result = InputText
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's one way to display alternate text depending on the answer given. Enter both paragraphs in the text, wrap each paragraph in a Bookmark, then select both and choose Format>Font>Hidden. The paragraphs will disappear. Then use this code to selectively show a paragraph:

```
Public HiddenTextVisibleb As Boolean, HiddenTextPrintsb As Boolean

Sub AutoOpen()
    If Options.PrintHiddenText = True Then
        HiddenTextPrintsb = True
        Options.PrintHiddenText = False
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True Then
        HiddenTextVisibleb = True
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowHideParagraphs()
    Dim InputText As String
    InputText = InputBox("Wat zijn de initialen en achternaam van de nieuwe medewerker?", "", "A. de Vries")
    If InputText = "Yes" Or InputText = "yes" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Paragraph1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Paragraph2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub AutoClose()
    If HiddenTextPrintsb = True Then
        Options.PrintHiddenText = True
    End If
    If HiddenTextVisibleb = True Then
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Toggling the .Font.Hidden property is a poor way of controlling the output, as what is seen and printed depends entirely on how the user has Word configured. If it's configured to display all formatting, no change may be apparent (i.e. both texts will still be visible) and, if Word is configured to print hidden text, both texts will still print (even if the hidden text is not visible)!!!

Comment: 30 years experience with Fortune 500 companies show your concern to be primarily theoretical. But the code is easily fixed, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the same data to different formfields; all you need do is configure the document to use cross-references to the first formfield's internal bookmark (in this case 'initialen_achternaam'). That way you only need write each datum once. When you're done writing to the formfields, all you need is a single line of code:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

As for varying the output depending on what you write to the 'initialen_achternaam' formfield, for example, you'd use an IF field in the document coded along the lines of:

```
{IF{REF initialen_achternaam}= "Yes" "Text for Yes", "Text for No"}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. The spaces represented in the field construction are all required.